# 2 node js + express applications sharing https port 443?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance where I am hosting a node js application (`NodeJS1`). I made a alternate version of the node js application (`NodeJS2`).

I have registered a single domain for the ec2 instance.

I also have ec2 security groups setup so that https uses 443 - **There seems to be no way to tell ec2 I'd like https on a custom port.**

Since the only possible https port is 443 is there any way I can have both nodejs applications share this port?

**EDIT**

I should also mention I am using express for my node js app. I am currently starting my app like this:

```
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3030);
fs = require('fs')
var sslOptions = {
                key: fs.readFileSync('./mykey.key'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('./mycert.crt'),
        };
https = require('https').createServer(sslOptions, app);
var server = https.listen(app.get('port'), function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('listening on ' + server.address().port)
});
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I am now trying this:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var fs = require('fs');
var proxyTable = {};

proxyTable['example.com/baz'] = 'http://localhost:3030';
proxyTable['example.com/buz'] = 'http://localhost:3031';

var httpOptions = {
    router: proxyTable
};
var httpsOptions = {
    router: proxyTable,
    ssl: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./mykey.key', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./mycert.crt','utf8')}
};
httpProxy.createServer(httpsOptions).listen(443, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('proxy listening...');
});
```

When I run it i get the following error:

```
/home/ec2-user/MacaronicWebApp/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:119
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Must provide a proper URL as target
    at ProxyServer.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/MacaronicWebApp/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:68:35)
    at Server.closure (/home/ec2-user/MacaronicWebApp/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:125:43)
```

I searched for this error and it looks like this method is outdated (not supported anymore) how can I get this behavior?

Comment: how do you envision figuring out which version should get which traffic?  you can probably solve your problem with virtualhosts

Answer (score 4):

You could technically run them as two separate apps listening on other ports and then utilize the npm package [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy). Using http-proxy, you could serve everything on 443, depending on the requested URI.

For example:

```
router: {
   'example.com/nodejs1': 'localhost:4000',
   'example.com/nodejs2': 'localhost:4001',
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes! If you set up `example.com` to be an SSL domain, you would just be taking the URI and using the proxy service to communicate with one of your node apps on another port. The app would then return through the proxy and back out through 443.

Comment: @Micheal I am a little confused still, I forgot to mention I am using express (see edit) how would http-proxy work with express? thanks!

Comment: @Micheal how do I use "router" in your example.. I dont see it in http-proxy docs.